# Compare row value with sum of other rows by given categories - Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a code, its code category and their corresponding values. I would like to compare the total of a category (A, B ) with the sum of their subtotal (A_1, B_2..) and add a column to the dataframe if the values are the same then return 1 otherwise 0.

| Month | code | code_category | Value | reporter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021M1 | A_1 | A_sub | 5 | ADC |
| 2021M1 | A_2 | A_sub | 10 | ADC |
| 2021M1 | A | A | 15 | ADC |
| 2021M1 | B_1 | B_sub | 4 | ADC |
| 2021M1 | B_2 | B_sub | 13 | ADC |
| 2021M1 | B | B | 14 | ADC |
| 2021M1 | B_1 | B_sub | 17 | FGH |
| 2021M1 | B_2 | B_sub | 0 | FGH |
| 2021M1 | B | B | 17 | FGH |

The desired output should be :

| Month | code | code_category | Value | reporter | subtot_correct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021M1 | A_1 | A_sub | 5 | ADC | 1 |
| 2021M1 | A_2 | A_sub | 10 | ADC | 1 |
| 2021M1 | A | A | 15 | ADC | 1 |
| 2021M1 | B_1 | B_sub | 4 | ADC | 0 |
| 2021M1 | B_2 | B_sub | 13 | ADC | 0 |
| 2021M1 | B | B | 14 | ADC | 0 |
| 2021M1 | B_1 | B_sub | 17 | FGH | 1 |
| 2021M1 | B_2 | B_sub | 0 | FGH | 1 |
| 2021M1 | B | B | 17 | FGH | 1 |

I aim just to flag the pair of month, reporter and code that have not the same subtotal, so any other suggestions on the column SUBTOT_CORRECT is welcome.

Comment: so since there are two `B`s, each `B` has to check only the group of `sub_B`s that is right before it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a more efficent/eligant way, but this is what I came up with.

Looks like the sub-categories also invlove the `'reporter'`, so groupby `'code_category'` and `'reporter'` and sum the values. Then merge that to the dataframe.

[image]

Next combine the main category and reporter to get a "key" value.

[image]

Count up the unique values within the "key" groups

[image]

Map those values into the dataframe column

[image]

Lastly, fill with `0` where not equal to `1`, and drop those columns used to merge on.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = ['Month','code','code_category','Value','reporter']

data = [
['2021M1',  'A_1',  'A_sub',    5,  'ADC'],
['2021M1',  'A_2',  'A_sub',    10, 'ADC'],
['2021M1',  'A',    'A',    15, 'ADC'],
['2021M1',  'B_1',  'B_sub',    4,  'ADC'],
['2021M1',  'B_2',  'B_sub',    13, 'ADC'],
['2021M1',  'B',    'B',    14, 'ADC'],
['2021M1',  'B_1',  'B_sub',    17, 'FGH'],
['2021M1',  'B_2',  'B_sub',    0,  'FGH'],
['2021M1',  'B',    'B',    17, 'FGH']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

grouped = df.groupby(['code_category', 'reporter']).sum()
grouped = grouped.reset_index(drop=False)
grouped = grouped.rename(columns=({'Value':'Sum'}))
df = df.merge(grouped, how='left', left_on=['code_category', 'reporter'], right_on=['code_category', 'reporter'])

df['key'] = df['code_category'].str.replace('_sub', '') + '_' + df['reporter']

lenUnique = dict(df.groupby(['key'])['Sum'].nunique())

df['subtot_correct'] = df['key'].map(lenUnique)
df['subtot_correct'] = np.where(df['subtot_correct'] == 1, df['subtot_correct'], 0)

df = df.drop(['Sum', 'key'], axis=1)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that works as expected indeed :)

Comment: excellent. be sure to accept the solution